# fatal error: lz4.h: No such file or directory #include "lz4.h"

Tags: compiling

```
Compiling (C++): prod/coretech/hub/compression/lz4_compressor.os
prod/coretech/hub/compression/lz4_compressor.cc:31:17: fatal error: lz4.h: No such file or directory
 #include "lz4.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [prod/coretech/hub/compression/lz4_compressor.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: That's an error message, what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

Install the dev library

```
sudo apt-get install liblz4-dev
```